# JS calculator guide, keep getting "not defined"

Tags: javascript

I am following a guide to make a calculator in JavaScript but am stuck on the first exercise. It keeps saying that `e` is not defined. When I define it, it keeps saying "key" is not defined. If I try to define it, I get `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration`key' before initialization`

Here's the code:

```
const calculator = document.querySelector(`.calculator`)
const keys = calculator.querySelector(`.calculator__keys`)



keys.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
    if (e.target.matches(`button`)) {

       // do something
    }
})

const key = e.target
const action = key.dataset.action


if (!action) {
    console.log('number key!')
  }
  if (
    action === 'add' ||
    action === 'subtract' ||
    action === 'multiply' ||
    action === 'divide'
  ) {
    console.log('operator key!')
  }

  if (action === 'decimal') {
    console.log('decimal key!')
  }

  if (action === 'clear') {
    console.log('clear key!')
  }

  if (action === 'calculate') {
    console.log('equal key!')
  }
```

Comment: TIP: Use quote rather than tilde key. Also, HOW e.target will be defined outside handler?

Comment: `const key = e.target` is outside the scope of your event callback, thus JS doesn't know what `e` is. You need to put this inside your callback. Can you also please post your HTML

Comment: @NickParsons   [Here's](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98) the entire guide I'm following. had no idea about the scope, we're currently going through this at the lectures but I always learn better by doing like this. Thanks! Feeling it's odd he did that though

Comment: @dux8 ah, I see. They may have made a mistake and didn't realize it at the time

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `e` outside of the click event handler callback. `e` means event. When a particular element is clicked, that event object will be created and passed to the callback function. Accessing that event outside will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `s to ' and it's not required but I'd also  recommend putting e in (). But the main point is your code needs to be inside the event  handler, otherwise "e" has no meaning outside of that context.

Do this:

```
const calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator')
const keys = calculator.querySelector('.calculator__keys')

keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches('button')) {
        const key = e.target
        const action = key.dataset.action

        if (!action) {
            console.log('number key!')
        }
        if (
            action === 'add' ||
            action === 'subtract' ||
            action === 'multiply' ||
            action === 'divide'
        ) {
            console.log('operator key!')
        }

        if (action === 'decimal') {
            console.log('decimal key!')
        }

        if (action === 'clear') {
            console.log('clear key!')
        }

        if (action === 'calculate') {
            console.log('equal key!')
        }
    }
});
```